# GLSL Shader compiles, but source is empty

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl

I'm trying to compile a GLSL shader, to which I use the following code.

Initialization

```
SDL_Window* boringInitStuff(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

    Uint32 windowFlags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;
    SDL_Window* sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Boooring", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 400, 400, windowFlags);

    SDL_GL_CreateContext(sdlWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    return sdlWindow;
}
```

File parser

```
void readFile(std::string path, std::string& data){
    std::ifstream f(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    data.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(f)),
                (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
}
```

Main

```
int main(int argv, char** args) {
    SDL_Window* sdlWindow = boringInitStuff();

    std::string buffer;
    readFile("./compile_test.vert", buffer);
    const char* cBuffer = buffer.c_str();

    GLuint shaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &cBuffer, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    while(!SDL_QuitRequested()){
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdlWindow);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to inspect the source code in gDEBugger, the source code is gone. Linking of course doesn't work aswell. The weird thing is, that the compilation error checking works.
**EDIT:** When I copy & paste the main part into another opengl project, it works.

[image]

Comment: "When I copy & paste the main part into another opengl project, it works." This suggests that you haven't yet isolated the problem. Try copying more into the new project until you can reproduce the issue, or create a duplicate of your project that has the issue and remove stuff  until the issue disappears. Either way will help you identify a minimal, complete, verifiable example that others can reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new Project in CLion and just copy-pasting the source code fixed the problem. Sadly I still don't exactly know why the error was there in the first place.

**EDIT:**

Apparently the name I give the project makes the difference.
When I give the Project the Name `OpenGLTestbed`, it does not work, the shaders won't compile correctly. But if I rename the project to anything else, in my case `Testbed`, it compiles the shaders correctly.

I'm working in CLion with MinGW.

Comment: You could save new project under a different location and then compare files for differences ..

Comment: Take a look at my edit. @Kromster

Comment: That's very strange, but good that you have it isolated better. +1 for edit